# Problem getting a string from a Combobox into a class variable [C#]

Tags: c#, wpf

The button function, should take whatever text is in the combo box and place it within sleeper.traintype

```
 private void Btn_Apply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sleeper.trainType = CmbBox_TrainType.Text;
            if (CmbBox_TrainType.Text == "Sleeper")
            {
                // instantiate the sleeper train
                sleeper.trainType = CmbBox_TrainType.Text;
            }
        }
```

My sleeper train class (inheriting from overall train class)

```
public class Sleeper : Train
{
    private string _intermediate, _intermediate1, _intermediate2, _intermediate3;
    private bool _cabin;
    public string intermediate
    {
        get
        {
            return _intermediate;
        }
        set
        {
            _intermediate = value;
        }
    }

    public string intermediate1
    {
        get
        {
            return _intermediate1;
        }
        set
        {
            _intermediate1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string intermediate2
    {
        get
        {
            return _intermediate2;
        }
        set
        {
            _intermediate2 = value;
        }
    }

    public string intermediate3
    {
        get
        {
            return _intermediate3;
        }
        set
        {
            _intermediate3 = value;
        }
    }
```

The train class:

```
 public class Train
{
    private string _trainID, _departureDay, _departureStation, _destinationStation, _departureTime, _trainType;
    private bool _firstClass;

    public string timePunctuation = ":";
    public string dayPunctuation = "/";

    public string trainID
    {
        get
        {
            return _trainID;
        }
        set
        {
            // check if the vlaue has letters & numbers and that the length is correct
            if(value.Length == 4 && Regex.IsMatch(value, "[A-Z][0-9]"))
            {
                _trainID = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FormatException("That train ID is not valid! (Example: AA11)");
            }
        }
    }

    public string departureDay
    {
        get
        {
            return _departureDay;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new FormatException("You need to choose a departure day!");
            } else
            {
                _departureDay = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string departureTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _departureTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value.Length != 5 || value.Contains(timePunctuation) == false)
            {
                throw new FormatException("The time must be in this format: (11:11 or 03:22)");
            } else
            {
                _departureTime = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string departureStation
    {
        get
        {
            return _departureStation;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new FormatException("You must enter a departure station!");
            } else
            {
                _departureStation = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string destinationStation
    {
        get
        {
            return _destinationStation;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new FormatException("You must enter a destination!");
            } else
            {
                _departureStation = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string trainType
    {
        get
        {
            return _trainType;
        }
        set
        {
            value = _trainType;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a combobox with three options `"Sleeper"`, `"Stopping"` and "Express". When using breakpoints next to `sleeper.trainType = CmbBox_TrainType.Text;` it creates my class but states that my `sleeper.trainType` variable is `null`. But it says that

> CmbBox_TrainType = "Sleeper"

Instantiate sleeper at the start with `Sleeper sleeper = new Sleeper();`
but have also tried to put it in the `if` and just before `sleeper.trainType = CmbBox_TrainType.Text;`

Comment: WPF/UWP and XAML were designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's pwoer and runs into issues at any other point. This does not look like the MVVM pattern. With it, this is just a two way binding. Maybe with a converter and/or operation between ViewModel and Model.

Comment: @Christopher thanks for the reply, I basically just copied this code from an old project I had, and it worked fine with exactly the same setup any glaring issues with it?

Comment: Please reduce the code in your question to a **minimal** example that demonstrates/exhibits the issue you are asking about. What have _intermediate1, _intermediate2, ..., departure day and station, etc... to do with your problem?

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "_When using breakpoints next to `sleeper.trainType = CmbBox_TrainType.Text`_"? Is the breakpoint above, below, or on the line? If you put the breakpoint above or on the line itself, and the breakpoint is being hit, then the line is not yet been executed -- in other words, `sleeper.trainType` would still have its initial value (null?). Step over this line in the debugger to see the assignment in this line changing the value of `sleeper.trainType`.

Comment: Check also that you have instantiated your sleeper object at the point where you assign to its 'traintype' attribute. You can't assign a value to an attribute of an object you have just declared and not instantiated.